# Oracle: Converting Varchar Column into Float

Tags: oracle

I'm attempting to clean up a poorly designed table with approximately 12,000 rows.  The table is saving user inputted data as a varchar.  I was wondering if there was a way to convert the entire column into a float and strip an extraneous text.  The column has null values, text values, and numbers all stored as text.

```
| Score   |
|---------|
| 1       |
| 2       |
| 2       |
| 3       |
| 300 EOW |
| 5.5     |
| (null)  |
| N/A     |
| 200     |
```

I attempted to use the following command but eventually receive a `ORA-01722` error.

```
TO_NUMBER(NVL(score,'0'),'9999D99','nls_numeric_characters=,.')
```

Any suggestions on how we can clean up the data?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Comment: What version of Oracle?  if 12.2 the `to_number` function has a new clause on what to return if it cannot parse the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution, without using a function, would be to use a regex to strip non-numeric characters before converting, like :

```
TO_NUMBER( 
    NVL(REGEXP_REPLACE(score, '[^1-9.]', ''), 0),
    '9999D99',
    'nls_numeric_characters='.'
)
```

Explanation of the regex :

```
[        # any character
  ^      # other than
  1-9    # 1, 2, 3,  ..., 9
  .      # and character . (dot)
]
```

NB : if you have numbers on serveral places in the string, they end up concatenated together, and then converted to a number. There are other possible options, for your use case, for example to use something like `REGEXP_SUBSTR(score, '[1-9.]')` to capture the first number in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you install this function listed:
    http://techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Then, you can call is_number

```
CASE WHEN is_number(<EXPRESSION>) = 1 THEN TO_NUMBER(<SAME EXPRESSION>) ELSE 0 END
```

Referenced Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_number (p_string IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN INT
IS
   v_new_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
   v_new_num := TO_NUMBER(p_string);
   RETURN 1;
EXCEPTION
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
   RETURN 0;
END is_number;
```

Comment: I think you would want to have the `ELSE 0` be `ELSE NULL`  since zero could be a valid data element, in general, but the OP's code appears to use `0` as a magic value of not a valid number.